# CodeIgniter4 Model returning data results

Tags: php-7, php-7.2, codeigniter-4

I am starting to dabble in CI4's rc... trying to get a head of the game. I noticed that the Model is completely rewritten.

Going through their documentation, I need some guidance on how to initiate the equivalent DB query builder in CI4.

I was able to leverage return $this->findAll(), etc... 
however, need to be able to be able to query w/ complex joins and also be able to return single records etc...

When trying something like

```
return $this->orderBy('import_date', 'desc')
      ->findColumn('import_date')
    ->first();
```

but getting error:

```
Call to a member function first() on array
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a model instantiated as

```
$userModel = new \App\Models\UserModel;
```

Now you can use it to get a query builder like.

```
$builder = $userModel->builder();
```

Use this builder to query anything for e.g.

```
$user = $builder->first();
```

Coming to your error.

```
return $this->orderBy('import_date', 'desc')
      ->findColumn('import_date');
```

`findColumn` always returns an array or null. So you can't use it as object. Instead you should do following.

```
return $this->orderBy('import_date', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: This is awesome.. if i needed to use join queries or even changing the return (ex single column or specific columns) how do i do so with the new way of using builder from the controller.

Comment: @Rick, Think of `$builder` as `$this->db` and it should all fall into place for you. There are some functions like `findColumn()`, `findAll()`, and `find()` that are actually part of the `Model` class. Look at the source code for those and you'll see that they are all (mostly all) using a `$builder` too.